# Rewrite article.php?title=variable to variable/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect `article.php?title=variable` to `variable/` using `.htaccess` but I'm not really sure what is wrong with my code. If I go to `http://site.com/variable/` it is redirecting me to `http://site.com/article.php//?titlu=article.php`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Rewrite urls for article
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ article.php?titlu=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture the query string. This should work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} title=([A-Za-z0-9_.-]*)
RewriteRule ^article.php /%1/? [R=301,L]
```

I'm assuming you don't want to redirect slashes... if you do you could add them to the string as well (or accept all characters).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} title=(.*)
RewriteRule ^article\.php /%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's still not redirecting me correctly, if I type `http://site.com/article.php?title=Elmo` it redirects to `http://site.com/Elmo/?title=Elmo`